# How do you skip a cell when using tabArray?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm using a tabArray on a worksheet that will cycle through cells F13, F17, and so on until F31 (All Odd numbered cells). Each cell is a drop down for a user to make a selection. If the cell in the array has a background that is grey, I want it to skip to the next cell in the array. For example, F21 has a grey background, however, if I make a selection in F13, the next cell that it moves to is F23. Every cell I make a selection change before cell F21 will automatically move to F23.

I've tried "Exit For" and "GoTo" with no success.

```
tabArray = Array  ("F13","F15","F17","F19","F21","F23","F25")

For I = LBound(tabArray) to UBound (tabArray) 
      If tabArray(I) = target.address(0,0) then 
       If I = UBound(tabArray) then 
       Me.Range(tabArray(LBound(tabArray))).Activate 

      Else  
      Me.Range(tabArray(I+1)).Activate

      end if 
  ElseIf Range(tabArray(I)).Interior.Colorindex = 15 then 
      If I = UBound(tabArray) then 
      Me.Range(tabArray(LBound(tabArray))).Activate 

     Else  
     Me.Range(tabArray(I+1)).Activate

     end if 
   end if 
Next I
```

If the cell background is grey for F23 and I make a selection in F13, I want the next cell that it moves to is F15, but the actual output is that it moves to cell F25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful how you skip around using your `tabArray`. The example below shows one way to do it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tabArray As Variant
    tabArray = Array("F13", "F15", "F17", "F19", "F21", "F23", "F25")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim nextHighlightCell As Long
    For i = LBound(tabArray) To UBound(tabArray)
        If tabArray(i) = Target.Address(0, 0) Then
            '--- a cell has changed within our tab list, so now find
            '    the next cell in the array that is not highlighted

            '--- increment to the next array position or wrap around
            If i = UBound(tabArray) Then
                j = LBound(tabArray)
            Else
                j = i + 1
            End If

            nextHighlightCell = -1
            Do While Not j = i
                If Range(tabArray(j)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Then
                    '--- this one is gray, so skip it
                    If j = UBound(tabArray) Then
                        j = LBound(tabArray)
                    Else
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Else
                    nextHighlightCell = j
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop

            '--- skip to the next indicated cell
            If Not nextHighlightCell = -1 Then
                Range(tabArray(nextHighlightCell)).Activate
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```